# Maven Plugins: components.xml and lifecycles.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm looking for the XSDs and documentation about META-INF/plexus/components.xml and META-INF/maven/lifecycles.xml which are used in Maven plugins.

The only documentation I've found so far is:

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifecycle XSD is at http://maven.apache.org/xsd/lifecycle-1.0.0.xsd (linked to from the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4-SNAPSHOT/maven-plugin-api/lifecycle-mappings.html).)

Plexus is a [project at Codehaus](http://plexus.codehaus.org), I didn't see any documentation of their schema there (but I didn't dig too deeply).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other (accepted) answer, [lifecycle-1.0.0.xsd](http://maven.apache.org/xsd/lifecycle-1.0.0.xsd) is documented in [the maven 3.2.1 docs](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-plugin-api/lifecycle-mappings.html).

As for the codehaus components schema, Codehaus is unfortunately no more ([Codehaus: The once great house of code has fallen](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2892227/codehaus-the-once-great-house-of-code-has-fallen.html)), but while the old site is now accessible via http://plexus.codehaus.org/, it looks like some of the materials didn't make it over, including [the components-1.3.0.xsd](http://plexus.codehaus.org/xsd/components-1.3.0.xsd) from the [plexus components docs](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-containers/plexus-container-default/plexus-components.html). Even [the Wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20160401000000*/http://plexus.codehaus.org/xsd/components-1.3.0.xsd) only has 404s and redirects for the schema.

As the components schema doesn't appear to be stored anywhere in the source archive, I assume that it was generated from code, but I haven't been able to find anything definitive or useful enough to reconstruct the schema.